# shell_exec('crontab -l') is empty when script was executed from cron job

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to delete specific cron job with my PHP script.
First of all I'm trying to get current cron jobs using shell_exec:

```
shell_exec('crontab -l');
```

When this script executing from webbrowser shell_exec returns all current cron jobs. But when this script executing from cron job shell_exec returns empty string. Why?

On another webhosting this works fine, but here I have this issue. I tried to find the reason or solution, tried different ways but didn't found any working solution.

Comment: every user gets their own cronjobs.

Comment: To elaborate on what Dagon said, you can use `crontab -u www-data -l` for example to see the cron listing for the `www-data` user. Probably worked on one server because your cron was running as the same user as your web server.

Comment: Dragon, Jeremy Harris, thanks for helping. I found the reason. cron runs under a limited environment. In my case I just needed to use full path: `shell_exec('/bin/crontab -l')` instaed of `shell_exec('crontab -l')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the entire path of the command, in this case, the path of `crontab`. 
Because when the crontab executes their jobs, there is no environment variable $PATH to look for binaries